# Adding Fragment to Android

Tags: java, android, fragment

T'm trying a very simple thing. Add a fragment through java code. But it is showing me error in (fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);). I'm not able to understand what is wrong over here. Please help. There are two classes the main class and the fragment class. and two layout the main layout and the fragment layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc.MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


package com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}




<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc.BlankFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>

package com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,container,false);
    return view;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why the above code is not working for me. but this did:

```
 BlankFragment firstFragment = new BlankFragment();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

This is not showing any error and it did work! thank you all.

Comment: I was going to suggest this approach and I am glad you posted the solution.  I believe because your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, that you need to use support libraries when applicable to accomplish the correct implementation of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up!!

An important rule when dealing with fragments is that your `activity` layout must include a container View in which you can insert the fragment.

Container can be a ViewGroup such as `FrameLayout` or a `LinearLayout`. In your case you are replacing a fragment in the `Fragment` - that is where things gone wrong.

Use the code below as a container -

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    ....
    ... />
```

Comment: Hello Wizard! I have changed the code in xlm file. But there is one error in line:transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

Answer (score 0):

First you must remember one thing:
**Fragments that are hard coded in XML, cannot be replaced.**
and there seems to be more than one problem with your code. First thing is the layout of MainActivity and another thing as per your need you need replace instead of adding fragment. Well in simple way i have refactored your code as following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc.MainActivity"
/>
```

**Your MainActivity Code:**

```
package com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  FragmentTransaction transaction = 
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();


 }
}
```

**And child fragment's layout as:**

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.chetan.fragmentprtc.BlankFragment">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

hope it will work after refactoring this much.

Comment: Hi Krantiz, Thank you for the help. I used your code but it is still showing error in line : transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);